# How to Approve aws sso login without Browser Support

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

***aws sso login --profile //profile name//*** is usually open browser and ask for approval is there any other way we can do this without browser. I have a situation where I need to setup aws cli in my docker container and I can only use aws sso login and I don't want to use any selenium to handle browser approval since its looks complex so I want to do all in cli itself…

Answer (score 10):

`aws sso login` takes a `--no-browser` flag which suppresses the browser launch

From there you can control the sso verification url via a browser automation library e.g. puppeteer.

> You can also get the verification url via aws sso-oidc actions/commands.

An example in golang using [go-rod](https://go-rod.github.io/#/get-started/README) is available [on github here](https://github.com/mziyabo/headless-sso) although this won't work with a non-mfa process flow, which is what you want here. The code at the link can be modded or updated to support that use-case with not a whole lot of effort.

Generally using **aws sso isn't recommedended for this type of use-case**. Instead, you're better off using IAM user credentials (while outside VPC for example) or if in a VPC - instance profiles if they're available.